# MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, sql, federated-storage-engine

I executed this query on my MySql Server and it is giving me "MySQL server has gone away" Error.In following query my both table have more then 1000000 rows.

```
SELECT a_tab_11_10.url as url,a_tab_11_10.c5 as 't1',a_tab_12_10.c3 as 't2' 
FROM a_tab_11_10 join a_tab_12_10 on (a_tab_11_10.url)=(a_tab_12_10.url) 
order by (a_tab_11_10.c5-a_tab_12_10.c3) desc limit 10
```

here is my log file but i am not getting it.
Thank you @Faisal for answer and i check my log file but i am not getting it..

> 110111 10:19:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   110111 10:19:51  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 945537221
>   110111 10:19:51 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   110111 10:19:51 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.1.36-community-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   110111 12:35:42 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown
>   110111 12:35:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   110111 12:35:43  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   110111 12:35:45  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 945538624
>   110111 12:35:45 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 1 plugins
>   110111 12:35:45 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete>
>   110111 12:36:39 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   110111 12:36:40  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 945538624
>   110111 12:36:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   110111 12:36:40 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.1.36-community-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   110111 12:36:40 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown
>   110111 12:36:40 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   110111 12:36:40  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   110111 12:36:42  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 945538634
>   110111 12:36:42 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 1 plugins
>   110111 12:36:42 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
>   110111 12:36:52 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   110111 12:36:52  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 945538634
>   110111 12:36:52 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   110111 12:36:52 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.1.36-community-log' socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>   110111 12:37:42 [Note] wampmysqld: Normal shutdown
>   110111 12:37:42 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
>   110111 12:37:42  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   110111 12:37:43  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 945538634
>   110111 12:37:43 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 1 plugins
>   110111 12:37:43 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
>   110111 12:37:46 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>   110111 12:37:46  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 945538634
>   110111 12:37:46 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   110111 12:37:46 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.1.36-community-log' 
>   socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Check the mysql error log. Its default location is inside the datadir of MySql.Post the relevant contents here.

Comment: I would start by running an explain on that query.

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

Check this link for more details -

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the connection you established with `mysql_connect` is closed and the handle MYSQL* is not valid anymore. It should have nothing to do with the query itself, in fact, if the query is wrong, you get a different error message.

You should check why the connection is closed. Does mysql daemon is restarted? do you use more than one thread and a different thread invokes `mysql_close`?

Comment: just a wild guess, what is the timelimit for your php scripts to run? maybe its timeouting and then closing the connection