# Mysql server gone away error

Tags: php, mysql, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4655165/mysql-server-has-gone-away)
>   [intermittent MySQL server has gone away error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149838/intermittent-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error)

I got mysql server gone away error while inserting the curl response detail. I checked the mysql connection is active.mysql connection is active still I got the above mentioned error.

Any suggestion please

Thanks

Comment: see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find many links for "How to fix 'MySQL server has gone away' (error 2006)".  For example:

- http://bogdan.org.ua/2008/12/25/how-to-fix-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error-2006.html
- http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=177965
- [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html

This is a configuration/networking issue.

The first thing to look at is your wait_timeout.

Comment: I tried by changing the wait_timeout but when this error happens, the wait_timeout get expired.please provide any solution.

Comment: @user1629371: Connect to the database *after* you have finished the curl operation.